# pthread_cond_signal on non-waiting cond_t variable

Tags: c++, pthreads, signals

As a part of my program, i use the command "pthread_cond_signal(cv)".
I want to use this line to "free" the waiting cv (but i don't know if this current cv is really waiting now).
Is it OK to do so also if this cv (a pthread_cond_t variable) is not waiting?   (I mean, pthread_cond_wait was not called upon it before)?
What would be the behavior in this case?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [pthread_cond_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html):

> The pthread_cond_signal() and pthread_cond_broadcast() functions have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on cond.

So nothing happens if nothing is waiting on the condition.